# RandomForest Classifier Output

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction, modeling

After my model prints out the output, it looks something like this

```
id        val
234       0.99
235       0.3
236       0
237       0.92
```

i wanted the val column to be binary, so did thresholding.

```
test[test["val"] < 0.5] = 0
test[test["val"] >= 0.5] = 1
```

after thresholding, for some reason my output looks like this

```
id        val
1         1
0         0
0         0
1         1
```

how do i make sure the id column doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

The condition you're providing only gives the rows that should change. Use `loc` and provide the column that should change as well.

```
test.loc[test["val"] < 0.5, "val"] = 0
test.loc[test["val"] >= 0.5, "val"] = 1
```

Output:

```
    id  val
0  234  1.0
1  235  0.0
2  236  0.0
3  237  1.0
```